# How does one setup EF Core 6 Identity Model to use Temporal Tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

EF6 has now released the ability to do temporal tables within the configuration and fluent api using the .ToTable(e => e.IsTemporal()) which is great and has worked for all the tables in my model.

However I'm using Identity Model (AspNetUser, AspNetRole, etc...) and those tables don't have that setup to use the .ToTable syntax to make them temporal; it looks like I have two options on how to make those temporal in the EF6 world; but I was hoping for a better option and was wondering if anyone knows of the ideal (or at least recommended) method

**Option 1: Manual SQL Statement**

In a migration I can do something like migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER TABLE AspNetUser SET(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = AspNetUserHistory))"). This is fine, but is manual and doesn't seem like it would be the recommended method.

**Option 2: Explicit Creation of Tables with Inheritance**

In my model I could create objects for all the Identity Model types (the public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser) and then map those to the same table name and include the (e => e.IsTemporal()); but that means creating all those objects which just inherit but don't add anything just to get temporal tables (hoping there is a better way)

**Option 3: Recommended Microsoft Method**

I wasn't able to find a recommended method to do this; hoping that it is something that does have a standard / recommended solution

Answer (score 1):

Utilisation of Identity Object Directly

It looks like we can use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity namespace directly to create those temporal tables like this

modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim>().ToTable(e => e.IsTemporal());